# link freetype in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode4, linker, freetype

This is very simple code basically stolen from fixbyproximity

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {  
allegro varibles
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
ALLEGRO_FONT *font18 = NULL;
ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image;
if (!al_init()) {                             //intialize ALLEGRO
return -1;
}
display = al_create_display(width, height);
if (!display) {
return -1;
}
al_install_mouse();
al_install_keyboard();
al_init_image_addon();
al_init_ttf_addon();
} ;
```

The error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FT_Init_FreeType
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/liballegro_ttf.5.0.dylib
Expected in: flat namespace
```

I'm really confused! The headers in the include folder are all there and Xcode does recognize the headers related to Freetype but I still am getting same error.

Is there a binary I'm supposed to link? because I can't find one, only headers =/
I did try to link libfreetype.a but all I got was another error

```
ignoring file /Users/michealdouble/Desktop/hilow1/libfreetype.a, file was built for archive    
which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must build FreeType it for **32bit**. By default it is build for **64 bits**.
Then add `libfreetype.a` to your project, and it should work.